# VirtueMart -- No pdf generation

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am using VM 2.0.8e   , everything works great except that I don't have PDF invoices.

The emails are sent to the customer correctly but no PDF attachments. I've looked into the configuration and there is nowhere I can specify I want PDF invoices.

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was the solution:

http://www.phoca.cz/phocapdf

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that pdf's are generated at all? In my case I had to create a folder vm-files and make it in a path not accessible by an URL. Then input it in the VM config.
Btw, Phoca PDF is for Virtuemart 1.x :)